# Javascript regular expression for negative Numbers with decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to test for this input:
[an optional negative sign] 2 digits [an optional . and an optional digit] like this:

`-34` or `-34.5333` or `34.53333` or `34` in **JavaScript**

This is what I came up with but it doesn't work!

```
/^(-)\d{2}(\.d\{1})$/
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/^-?\d{2}(\.\d+)?$/
```

Comment: some invalid *numeric* values pass the test with this regex : `'-00.23', `-0``

Answer (score 4):

this regex matches any valid integer.

```
/^0$|^-?[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$/
```

you can modify this to suite your needs :

```
/^-?[1-9]\d{0,1}(\.[1-9]{1})?$/
```

this matches 2.1, 21.4, 3, 90...

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps regex is **not** needed.

```
function validate(val){
    return isNaN(val)?false:(Math.abs(Math.floor(val)).toString().length==2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
/^-?[0-9]{2}(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/^(-)?\d{2}(\.\d+)?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression:

```
-?\d{2}[.]?\d*
```

Answer (score 0):

what your regEx ( /^(-)\d{2}(.d{1})$/ ) does is:

> Start with requiring the negative and then correctly your requiring
>   two digits, then with the "." your requiring any character, you should
>   strict it to the symbol with "\", and finally comes one digit.

correct example code would be:

```
var str = '-34.23';
pat=/^\-?\d{2}(\.(\d)*)?$/g;
str.match(pat);
```

More testable example: http://jsfiddle.net/GUFgS/1/

use the "?" after the group to make that match an option i.e  (\.\d*)?

Answer (score 0):

This below simple html code will validate the +ve & -ve numbers of 2 digits plus optional minimum of 1 digit after decimal point.

**JS Code:**

```
    function validateNum() {
        var patForReqdFld = /^(\-)?([\d]{2}(?:\.\d{1,})?)$/;
        var value = document.getElementById('txtNum').value;

        if(patForReqdFld.test(value)) {
            alert('Valid Number: ' + value);
        } else {
            alert('Invalid Number: ' + value);
        }
    }
```

**HTML Code:**

```
    <label>Enter Number:&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtNum" onBlur="validateNum()"/>
```