# Validate negative and positive decimal numbers with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to build a regex which will allow both negative and positive decimal numbers with the following rules.

1. there can not be more than 2 digits after decimal point
2. Decimal point is optional
3. Total length including decimal point should not exceed 12 char
4. if no decimal point is there, max length should not exceed 9 char

Can anyone help me out? thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Will the minus count as a character in the string?  What about if there are more than 2 decimal places, but are all 0s?

Comment: No the minus wont count within the 12 limit. more than 2 decimal places are not allowed even if they are 0s. thank you :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript regular expression for negative Numbers with decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7749627/608639).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check this regex.

```
^[+-]?[0-9]{1,9}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

This regex says

- sign is optional
- at least one and max 9 digits as integer part
- if decimal point is there, at least one and max two digits after it.

Comment: This link helped me to write and test this regex http://erik.eae.net/playground/regexp/regexp.html

Comment: can you refer some nice tutorial about regex?

Comment: Test fails for input 1-2

Answer (score 3):

It is pretty straightforward since 12 - 9 == 3 for two decimals + the dot.

```
var re = new RegExp('^-?\\d{1,9}(\\.\\d{1,2})?$');
```

authorizes

- `-123456789`
- `-123456789.1`
- `-123456789.12`
- `0`
- `0.12`

but will not accept

- `01234567890123` more than 12 decs
- `123.` a dot without decimals
- `123.123` more than two decimals
- `.` or `.12` (missing 0)

Comment: I think you're missing double backslashes in the regular expression.

Comment: Thank you but it accepts value greater than 12 char in total, like 12345678912.00

Comment: @ManasSaha fixed (typo), provided the `-` is not counted in the limit

Answer (score 1):

My own regex:

```
var rgx = /^(-{1}?(?:([0-9]{0,10}))|([0-9]{1})?(?:([0-9]{0,9})))?(?:\.([0-9]{0,3}))?$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var NumberToValidate = 48428;
        var valid =  /^([0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$/.test(NumberToValidate);
        {
        if (!valid)
    alert("Invalid Quantity!!\nThe Quantity cannot be Zero\n or a part of a Unit !");
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
/(?:^(?:(?:[1-9][0-9]{1,})|0)\.[0-9]{1,}$)|^[1-9]+[0-9]*$/
```