# Validate Negative Number

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to make a new function that will validate the field but allow for negative numbers aswell as positive e.g. =/- 999.99 . Would anyone have a quick and easy solution. Thanks

```
function validateNumber(thenumber){
    try{
        validnumbers = "0123456789.,";
    valid = false;
    for(i=0;i<thenumber.length;i++){
       if (validnumbers.indexOf(thenumber.charAt(i)) == -1)
       {
          valid = false;
          break;
       }
       else
          valid = true;
    }
    return valid;
    }catch(e){}
   }
```

Comment: You might be better off to use a RegExp http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460773/regex-validate-negative-and-positive-decimal-numbers

Comment: How about `Math.abs()`

Comment: This will return `true` for `...`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about this simple function?

```
function validateNumber(thenumber)
{
    thenumber = thenumber.replace(".", "").replace(",", ".");

    return !isNaN(thenumber);
}
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j42p1kjp/)**</kbd>

The function removes dots then replaces comma with dots. Then it uses [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) with negation to return if its valid or not. You may want to add a check if `thenumber` is a *string* to prevent runtime errors.

Comment: @topcat3, why the snarky comment?  If the answer does not meet your needs, kindly explain why.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown no snarky comment. your help was greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `isNaN`

```
function validateNumber(thenumber){
    return !isNaN(thenumber);
   }
```

`isNaN` will return false for both positive and negative numbers

Comment: @Jongware, no it does not. Have you tried it? I have

Comment: Is parseInt really needed ? Or could it lead to unexpected results in some edge-cases ?

Comment: I have a question: Why this `!isNaN(parseInt("13.12313,123dasd.asd1"))` is evaluating to `true` ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the better way to do this is using regular expresions:
The search() method uses an expression to search for a match, and returns the position of the match(return -1 in other case).Here is an example:

```
public function validNumber(number)
{
    return number.search("^[+-]?[0-9]{1,9}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$") > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function isNumber(value) {
  value = value.replace(',', '.');
  return !isNaN(value);
}

function isNegative(value) {
  return (isNumber(value) && value<0);
}

function isPositive(value) {
  return (isNumber(value) && value>0);
}
```

and as bonus (:

```
function isNumberWithDots(value) {
  value = value.split(',').join('').split('.').join('');
  return !isNaN(value);
}
```

Comment: *" negative numbers aswell as positive"*.

Comment: I believe your `isNumber` function may return wrong value. E.g.: If you try to check `12.123,12` it will become `12.123.12` and `isNumber` will return false. It is ok, but in fact the number was valid, right?

Comment: of course 12.123.12 is not number, 12.12312 is number.

Comment: added function as bonus :)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, since when are `12.123,12` or `12.123.12` valid numbers?

Comment: sorry not looked at who's writing :)

Comment: @Sparky in my culture(pt-br) `12.123,12` is a valid number, and it may be valid in another culture, since OP didn't specified a culture.

Comment: @num8er `12.123.12` maybe invalid, but what I said is if you try to check for `12.123,12` your function will check as `12.123.12`, what changes everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```
(number < 0)
```

It will be evaluated by JavaScript by first attempting to convert the left hand side to a number value.

Further details can be found here:

[Javascript negative number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571717/javascript-negative-number)

Conversely, this expression:

```
(number > 0)
```

will be evaluated by JavaScript in the same manner.

Comment: He also wants to validate positive numbers.