# Regular expression to allow first letter + or - or number

Tags: regex

I want a regular expression like first letter should be + or - or number and if it is - or + followed letter should be number and also allow 2 decimal point. If enter + or - followed letter could not be . (dot).

I am trying with following reg ex but few condition is not working properly.

```
/^[+-]*\d*\.?\d?\d?/g;
```

Comment: I'm **sure** there's a duplicate somewhere.

Comment: What's wrong in duplication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple regular expression for a decimal with a precision of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308122/simple-regular-expression-for-a-decimal-with-a-precision-of-2)

Comment: It's different and not works for me.

Comment: It's the same, just need to prepend `[+-]?`

Comment: Not a code I am talking about my requirement.

Comment: Yes, and it satisfies all of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx- Validate negative and positive decimal numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460773/regex-validate-negative-and-positive-decimal-numbers)

Answer (score 2):

You basically want your string to begin with a number, that can be prefixed by a plus or minus and has at most 2 decimal points.

The regex for this looks like this:

```
/^[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

1. `[+-]?`The regex allows a string to start with a + or minus sign, but not necessarily.
2. `\d+`It is then followed by a number.
3. `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` That number may have a dot with up to two following numbers. (precision of 2)

Comment: Before someone comments: Special chars do not need to be escaped in or groups (`[]`)

Comment: Not working.It allowing me 1+++,1----,1.... and do not allow to add + or - in front.

Comment: @Rafikmalek Because those strings are correcty accordingly to your question. The string starts with a number. The `+++`, `---` and `...` part is grouped by the `.*` (4.) and cannot be determined by me, because you did not specify it in your question. Adjust 4. accodingly to your specifications to rule those answers out.

Comment: No should strat with number or + or -

Comment: @Rafikmalek It starts with the number 1 :-)

Comment: and there should be only one time existence of + - and .IF you are using + you cant use - sign and vise versa.

Comment: @Rafikmalek Well, i removed the part after the numbers. Now only numbers are allowed. Hope thats what you ment :-) If you want to use strings afterwards just add `[^+-.]` before the `$` in the regex.